# On iMovie 10.0.9, how can I export smaller video files?

Tags: video, imovie, encoding, video-editing

On my Macbook Air, I recorded a video using iMovie 10.0.9.  Then I clicked Share > File.

**The resolution is 1280x720.  At "High" quality, the file size of the resulting mp4 video was 1 GB for just 11 minutes of video!  That's enormous!**

**As a comparison, on my Windows 7 computer, using Camtasia, I'm able to record an even *higher* resolution video (1920x1080), and its file size is 68 MB.**

**How can I export a video from iMovie in a way that makes the file much smaller?**

I tried choosing "Low" quality, and then the file size was about 300 MB.  (That's still big! And I'm not liking the idea of it being *low* quality, which was not necessary in Windows.)

This really matters to me because I upload my mp4 videos to various websites, and the upload takes far too long if the files are really large.

How would I be able to export a full-resolution high quality video from iMovie (into mp4 format) and still have the file size be just 68 MB for 11 mins of video?  What are my options?

Thanks.